# In Retrofit, why use one method per interface

Tags: java, android, rest, networking, retrofit2

I am new to android and REST client. I am using retrofit to build an app to communicate with an API.

Many tutorials said the best practice is to declare 1 method per interface (so many methods means many interfaces).

Examples: if I want 2 method, a GET and a POST. I will need two interfaces:

```
public interface GetService {
    @GET("/abc/xyz")
    Call <ABC> getService();
}

public interface PostService {
    @POST("/abc/def")
    Call<XYZ> postServer(@Body XYZ content);
}
```

and in the main_activity I will need to call

```
//call get
GetService get = ServiceGenerator.createService(GetService.class);
ABC call1 = get.getService();
//call post
PostService post = ServiceGenerator.createService(PostService.class);
XYZ call2 = post.postService();
```

Why can't I have only one interface like this:

```
public interface APIInterface {
@GET("/abc/xyz")
    Call <ABC> getService();

@POST("/abc/def")
    Call<XYZ> postServer(@Body XYZ content);
}
```

and in the Main_Activity, I only need to do the following:

```
APIInterface api = ServiceGenerator.createService(APIInterface.class);
ABC call1 = api.getService();
XYZ call2 = api.postServer();
```

Comment: Is it possible you're mixing up things? Often it's good to have simple interfaces with only one method, because you can use lambdas there. But it still relates to the use-case itself. If you think it's a good idea to have more than one method in the interface, put more than one method there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to follow this "good practice" with one service per interface. If you use one interface per **business part** like below, it's ok.

```
public interface ProductRestService {
    @GET("/product/****")
    Call <Product> getProduct(long id);

    @PUT("/product/****")
    Call <Product> update(long id, @Body Product product);

    @POST("/product/****")
    Call <Product> create(@Body Product product);

    @DELETE("/product/****")
    Call <Void> deleteProduct(long id);
}
```

The goal is just to avoid an interface with all your app's services

Comment: Thanks! But in terms of performance, is it better to have many interfaces or as few as possible?

Comment: If you declare one service per interface, you have to create a service with retrofit for each services by calling createService() . So it's more expensive than a business architecture like in my example and less readable. Here, you just have to create one ProductService instead of four. I didn't measure the cost of the createService() method but I think it's not totally negligible.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I wonder why some people were recommending it, though.

Answer (score 0):

Put everything in one interface. easy for you to call it anywhere. if you have difference Base Url, then you can have different interface. depends on developer

```
public interface RestApi {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Token")
    Observable<TokenResponse> normalLogin(
        @Field("grant_type") String grant_type,
        @Field("UserName") String UserName,
        @Field("Password") String Password
    );

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Account/VerifyExternalLogin")
    Observable<ExternalLoginResponse> externalLogin(
            @QueryMap HashMap<String,String> option
    );

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("Account/ResetPassword")
    Observable<ResetResponse> requestPassword(
            @Field("Email") String email
    );

    @GET("Profile")
    Observable<UserDetail> getProfile();

    @GET("History/{cartId}")
    Observable<OrderHistoryResponse> getHistoryDetail(
            @Path("cartId") int cartId
    );
}
```